# Need help on Bootstrap Pull Push issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, push, pull

My first question here. I got headache in using bootstrap pull and push on the website i'm working on.
 This is what I want to achieve:
1. On large view port:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtPuP.png
2. On mobile view:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7iVP.png

I'm using bootstrap to pull the block B to the left.
The problem is that it is important to have **block A and B: width 4, and block C: width 8.** I don't know how to do it because the total width will be more than 12. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: can you show this problem in fiddle??

Comment: hi sorry, nvm, it's working alr, it doesn't use pull and push anymore, but so long as its working haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use column nesting in bootstrap to give A & B width:4 and C width:8.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="col-md-12" style="height:100px;background:red;">A</div>
  <div class="col-md-12" style="height:100px;background:green">B</div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-8" style="height:200px;background:blue">C</div>
```

OR without nesting the code(in this **C** will be above **B** in small devices) will look like this

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="height:100px;background:red;">A</div>
<div class="col-md-8 float" style="height:100px;background:blue">C</div>
<div class="col-md-4" style="height:100px;background:green">B</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media (min-width: 992px) 
  { 
    .float
    {
      float:right!important;
      height: 200px!important;
    } 
  }
```

Link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arshadmuhammed/0qvL5bxg/

Comment: Hi! yes, I want to make C above B in small device, so i use the float method, and it's working! When i look at your answer, it seems so simple... I need to learn more. Thank you